# All the dates and time for files in a folder in windows

Tags: windows, filesystems, deployment, utilities

In windows file explorer, I would like to go through all the subfolders in a folder and identify all the files in those folders and sort them by latest date and time.

I am trying to figure out when was the last time any file(s) that was deployed to any of those subfolders.

Comment: I think Powershell is your friend here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If i assume you want to do that in windows file explorer,
just point it in the proper forlder and type  * in the search box (it will do it recursively)

Now show detail view in explorer and click on "date modified" column .

And voila! you 'll have all your files recursively sorted by modification time.

If you wanted that list (only filename) on a text file ordered by modification time, just open command prompt and type

```
dir /s /b /on yourfolder >logfile.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

In Powershell, try

```
get-childitem -recurse | sort -property creationtime
```